# Programming an ATtiny13A with Arduino Mega 2560 (blink sketch load wrong, LED stays on)

Tags: arduino, attiny

I'm trying to program an [ATtiny13A](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATtiny13A) with an Arduino Mega 2560. I load the blink sketch, and AVRDUDE says it uploads completely, but the LED on the ATtiny13A doesn't blink; it just stays on (it's specified on pin 4), I've tried other pins, with the same result.

What may be the issue, and why is the loop not looping correctly? I'd love to hear the debugging process of others on issues like this, because I'm out of options.

I've tried different IDE versions (I'm on a Windows 7 64-bit machine), I've downloaded both this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ard-core13/ and https://github.com/tekstop/attiny/tree/Arduino1 to try and get a more accurate ATtiny13A specification, if it had to do with the specifications in the board, but none of them change the result.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to switch to Arduino IDE v. 1.0.

Look at comments in blog post *[Programming ATtiny13 using Arduino ISP (and all the hacking involved!)](http://tekstop.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/programming-attiny13-using-arduino-isp-and-all-the-hacking-involved/)*.